# How to handle special symbols such as GC=F in quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

How to handle special symbols such as `GC=F` in quantmod. `GC=F` is the symbol for the front month gold futures contract in yahoo. Example below:

```r
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("^GSPC")     # this will return symbol GSPC and stock data
getSymbols("GC=F")      # this will not work at all, returns missing values
```

Comment: https://www.quantmod.com/documentation/getMetals.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue. Running the below code will return the data for the last few days. There is a missing value in there for October 4th which is consistent with the data on the yahoo page as seen [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GC%3DF/history?p=GC%3DF). All the missing data points are Sundays. If you want to remove these records, you can use `na.exclude` or remove all the weekend days with a function.

```
library(quantmod)

gold <- getSymbols("GC=F", auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2020-10-01")
gold

           GC=F.Open GC=F.High GC=F.Low GC=F.Close GC=F.Volume GC=F.Adjusted
2020-10-01    1884.1    1909.6   1882.5     1908.4         730        1908.4
2020-10-02    1893.9    1913.0   1893.9     1900.2         530        1900.2
2020-10-04        NA        NA       NA         NA          NA            NA
2020-10-05    1898.9    1915.6   1884.7     1912.5        1360        1912.5
2020-10-06    1906.6    1918.0   1874.4     1901.1         968        1901.1
2020-10-07    1874.1    1889.8   1873.1     1883.6          50        1883.6
2020-10-08    1893.0    1893.0   1882.7     1888.6         348        1888.6
2020-10-09    1909.3    1929.1   1905.1     1919.5         348        1919.5
```

just removing the empty days with `na.exclude`

```
na.exclude(gold)
           GC=F.Open GC=F.High GC=F.Low GC=F.Close GC=F.Volume GC=F.Adjusted
2020-10-01    1884.1    1909.6   1882.5     1908.4         730        1908.4
2020-10-02    1893.9    1913.0   1893.9     1900.2         530        1900.2
2020-10-05    1898.9    1915.6   1884.7     1912.5        1360        1912.5
2020-10-06    1906.6    1918.0   1874.4     1901.1         968        1901.1
2020-10-07    1874.1    1889.8   1873.1     1883.6          50        1883.6
2020-10-08    1893.0    1893.0   1882.7     1888.6         348        1888.6
2020-10-09    1909.3    1929.1   1905.1     1919.5         348        1919.5
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the auto.assign switch. Appreciate your help!